# calling out a variable inside a function in a while loop

Tags: python

I using a python and opencv to detect how many faces it could detect may problem is it could not take out the varieble inside **def gen_frames():**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from datetime import datetime
import cv2
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

app=Flask(__name__)
camera=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
Classifier=cv2.CascadeClassifier('Vhicle_37.xml')
No_of_face=0

#Stored data to csv
def FacesCount():
    with open('data.csv','a') as f:
        Count = str(No_of_face) #here should the No_of_face be store to generate the Counted face   
        now =  datetime.now()
        dtString = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        f.writelines(f'\n{Count},{dtString}')
        time.sleep(1)

def Vchie():
        while True:
           FacesCount()

#gen_frames() generate Video Stream
def gen_frames():

    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read()  # read the camera frame
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            img=cv2.resize(frame,(0,0),None,0.40,0.40)
            
            gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


            Faces = Classifier.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=2)
                
            for (x,y,w,h) in Faces:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), thickness=2)
                
            No_of_face=len(Faces) #this the variable I am trying to access to def FacesCount()
             

            cv2.putText(img,f'Faces:{str(len(Faces))}',(10,100),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.5,(255,0,0),2)
           
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
            img = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + img + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__=='__main__':
    f=Process(target=Vchie)
    f.start()

    app.run()
```

the code above was the whole source

**My Goal**

1.Accesss Variable No_of_face for storing data

2.Timer wont affect other function

**Problem**

1.No_of_face could not be access even though marked as Global

please help if there is another method to get the data from the varieble please share to me thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] (be mindful of the "minimal" – it very, very likely does not need ``opencv``). The code as shown doesn't do anything because nothing is run; *how* these two blocking parts are run is important for how they interact.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `global No_of_face` before using it in the FacesCount function.

```
def FacesCount():
    global No_of_face
    .........
```

Comment: it did not work man thanks for trying to help

Comment: this *is* the solution (for 1. at least). if it doesn't work, you made another mistake, such as you put this in the wrong place. it needs to go at the TOP of a function definition (inside the function), before any other code in the function.